# While loop in php not finishing loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I'm working on this code and trying to get it to only pull 4 entries from the repository and it keeps pulling all of my entries.

```
<?php
     while ( $i < 4) {
            foreach ($churchEvents->getResults() as $churchEvent){
                ?>  
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <?php echo $churchEvent->getStructuredText('church-events.event-title')->asText(); ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cuntd" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <?php echo $churchEvent->getDate('church-events.event-start-date')->asDateTime()->format('l, F j, Y'); ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody> 

                <?php $i++; } } ?>
```

Comment: do you ever initialize $i to 0?

Comment: "trying to get it to only pull 4 entries from the repository" - Do you expect the foreach-loop to be "aborted" after four iterations?

Comment: @VolkerK tries to say: `$churchEvents->getResults()` probably "pulls" all entries, according to the name?

Comment: Why dont u pull only 4 records from db first and just skip that while?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two loops, but there is no reason to have two. The inner one (`foreach`) already iterates through all the *$churchEvents*, so the outer one (`while`) will not make it do less.

Remove the outer `while` loop and the `$i++;`, and make the inner loop only loop over the first four elements.

For this, you can use the `=>` syntax in the `foreach` statement to get the value of *$i*, and then add an `if` to exit the loop:

```
<tbody>  
<?php
foreach ($churchEvents->getResults() as $i => $churchEvent){
    if ($i >= 4) break;
?>  
    <tr>
        <td> <?= $churchEvent->getStructuredText('church-events.event-title')->asText() ?>
        </td>
        <td class="cuntd" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <?= $churchEvent->getDate('church-events.event-start-date')->asDateTime()->format('l, F j, Y') ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
```

Note that `tbody` should not be generated more than once, so it should stay out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because while is outside foreach.

```
while ( $i < 4) {
        foreach ($churchEvents->getResults() as $churchEvent){
```

At the start of foreach try **if** combine with **break**.

```
//you don't need while here anymore
foreach ($churchEvents->getResults() as $churchEvent){
if ($i >= 4) {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method names are distinctive enough to make a guess what library/api you're using: (http://prismicio.github.io/php-kit/namespaces/Prismic.html), right?

The [`->getResults()` method](http://prismicio.github.io/php-kit/classes/Prismic.Response.html#method_getResults) returns an array. So, there are several options; here are some of them:

Using an [SPL LimitIterator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php):

```
<?php
// only fetching the first four entires
$iter = new LimitIterator( new ArrayIterator($churchEvents->getResults()), 0, 4);
foreach ($iter as $churchEvent) { ?>  
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $churchEvent->getStructuredText('church-events.event-title')->asText(); ?></td>
            <td class="cuntd" style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $churchEvent->getDate('church-events.event-start-date')->asDateTime()->format('l, F j, Y'); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
<?php 
}
```

---

Using [array_slice()](http://docs.php.net/array_slice) to get the first four elements and then iterate over those four:

```
<?php
// copying the first four element of the array
$arr = array_slice($churchEvents->getResults(), 0, 4);
foreach ($arr as $churchEvent) { ?>  
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $churchEvent->getStructuredText('church-events.event-title')->asText(); ?></td>
            <td class="cuntd" style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $churchEvent->getDate('church-events.event-start-date')->asDateTime()->format('l, F j, Y'); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
<?php 
}
```

---

(prefered option:) Only request four items/fragements:
I'm not familiar with the api but at the very least there's the method [<kbd>`pageSize(integer  $pageSize) : \Prismic\SearchForm`</kbd>](http://prismicio.github.io/php-kit/classes/Prismic.SearchForm.html#method_pageSize) which sets the resultset size for the pagination. Maybe you can even limit the number of results in the response with some predicates or a limit-clause or something, i.e. only request what you really need.